# React Native app - Material icon are different in Android and iOS after React Native upgrade

Tags: android, react-native

I have upgrade the react native version from 0.64.4 to 0.69.12. But after upgrade, for some reason, the material icons are now changed in Android app. In iOS, they are showing correctly.

I am using `MaterialCommunityIcons` from `react-native-vector-icons`. I tried to clear npm cache clear, yarn cache clear, gradle clean but nothing happened.

This is how I am using it:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'

<Icon
    name={icon}
    size={isLearn ? 50 : iconSize}
    color={focused ? Colors.primary : '#757575'}
/>
```

Does anyone know what is the issue and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by removing the `react-native-vector-icons` completely from, package.json, build.gradle and then added it again.